# Can bipolar develop in childhood?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology, psychiatry, bipolar-disorder

Is it possible to develop bipolar in childhood? Does the same diagnostic criteria for bipolar in adults apply for children?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it is referred to as Disruptive Mood Dysregulation Disorder in DSM 5 and is characterized by persistent irritability and frequent episodes of extreme, out-of-control behavior.

Comment: This seems partially backed up in the Pediatric News article ["When is it bipolar disorder and when is it DMDD?"](https://www.mdedge.com/pediatricnews/article/96590/mental-health/when-it-bipolar-disorder-and-when-it-dmdd): _"A new diagnosis called disruptive mood dysregulation disorder (DMDD) was introduced into the DSM-5 to describe these chronically irritable children and, in part, to reduce the number of children receiving a bipolar diagnosis."_ However, it makes no claim that it is _always_ diagnosed as DMDD as you imply in this answer. -1